# converting md5 hashes in urls to be shorter shorter

Tags: php, image, url, upload, md5

Im working on a image hosting website, and to prevent "already exists" error, i md5 the images that are being uploaded, the problem is that the URL to that website is already quite long plus the whole MD5 hash makes it even longer, is there any way to make the URL shorter?

Comment: Can you give an example of the URL with a hash?

Comment: http://localhost/useruploads/aa0a5af69375e2ebbbe011128bf28ae9.gif

Comment: You would defeat the purpose of your original intent.

Comment: If there's a specific reason for using md5 as a filename, then let it be so. However, you could just use the Unix timestamp which will greatly reduce the file's length and will be unique.

Comment: @Fred-ii- if OP's site has average traffic, isn't their chance of collision while using timestamp?

Comment: @blo You do have a point there. Adding a 3-5 char. `rand()` to timestamp would fix that. However, would be better using a DB with unique auto-increment ID.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah auto increment is the best option here plus it would result in relatively short url.

Comment: @blo Exactly, one good way to do about it.

Comment: @IliyaGolik You can also save yourself a bit of space by having your upload folder's name shorter. For instance `up` or `up1` along with [`uniqid`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) for random sequence, that way there stands to be no collision.

Comment: You all did not understand my question what i was asking is if there's a shorter has than MD5?

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to use the `md5` string as your image filename. To ensure the uniqueness of the images, you can try the following solution:

- `md5()` every new image a user uploads
- Store the `md5()` value in a database
- Next time a user uploads an image, check if the item already exists in your database
- If exists, prevent user from uploading the image. Else, proceed.
- Repeat

Comment: @IliyaGolik: Hi, I don't understand your question. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

you can keep a id to the hash value mapping with you on the image hosting server. You can store this mapping in redis or mysql as both are persistant databases.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **name of image and time** when uploaded to make it unique but shorter. use like this

```
$img_name = $uploaded_name.time().$file_ext;
```

Hence the name will be shorter but unique.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the unix timestamp to ensure a new and unique file name all the time and keep is length shorter as well.